# Positioning a media object and list group together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need put something like this:

```
<div class="media">
  <img src="..." class="mr-3" alt="...">
</div>
```

on top of something like that:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

inside the first column on something like that:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

on a way they could work like one only thing, the bottom of the media object and top of the list group fitting together one to another continuosly (with the same width for both elements), and the top of this set with margin zero with the top of the page, overlapping the fixed navbar placed above the container in the third snippet code, and pushing the `nav-items` elements inside the navbar to the right of the image.

**update 2**

css:

```
.navbar {
  z-index: -1;
}
.navbar-nav {
  z-index: 2;
}
.list-group {
  margin-top: -96px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

with this, the `navbar` stays behind the `list-group`, as intended, but I am unable to click in any of the links on the navbar.

Comment: Can you please provide a image or something related to your desired output. This will make us able to help you.

Comment: it's something roughly like that: https://imgur.com/a/K4v5QEz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using this css style:

```
.list-group {
  margin-top: -128px;
  width: 180px;
}
li.list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
}
.media img {
  padding: 0;
}
.bd-placeholder-img {
  padding: 0;
}
```

I put the `media object` inside the first item in the `list-group` (the other items are links `a.list-group-item`, therefore the use of `li-list-group-item` in the css).

Answer (score 1):

> the bottom of the media object and top of the list group fitting together one to another continuosly (with the same width for both elements)

I just used your code and this pretty much works

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" class="mr-3" alt="...">
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group" style="width: 200px;">
          <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You just need to **set the same width to both the image and the ul.**
I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question and this is not what you were seeking.

Also why would you want to hide your nav by overlapping it with an image. Then what purpose does your navbar serve?

Comment: I do not want hide the navbar. usually the navbar has a `nav-brand` item, and the links in it will be placed to the right. this `sidebar` will replace this `nav-brand`, but instead of being between the `nav` tags, are inside the `container` tag.

Comment: The above code is for the same width of the image and ul. For the overlapping,you can try a ```negative margin-top value on first col-sm``` such as ```margin-top:-30px``` if that doesn't make any changes to your other code.

Comment: I've tried adding `style="width=180px;"` to the `list-group` but it remains being displayed larger than the image (don't know if it's relevant, but how I don't have a jpeg to use with the tag `img`, I am using a placeholder `svg`, with the size 180x360).

Comment: also, using `margin-top` (the value is close to -80px), the `list-group` stays behind the `navbar`. I want the `navbar`  behind the `list-group` and the `nav-item` pushed to the right of the `list-group`.

Comment: Ok, I managed the issue in my last comment just by trying experiment with the `z-index` of the `list-group` and `navbar` (see update 2). But right now, I am unable to click on the links in the navbar. Do you know how to fix that.

Comment: Ok, I already found the solution for this last problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311574/unable-to-click-on-the-links-on-a-navbar