# Unable to click on the links on a navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can click all other links in the page, including in the `list-group` (when I have any), and access all paths from my project (when I directly access them using the url mapped in my application), but none of the links in the navbar are acessible right now.

Below the code:

```css
    .navbar {
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .list-group {
      margin-top: -128px;
      width: 180px;
    }
    
    li.list-group-item {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .media img {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .bd-placeholder-img {
      padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          
        </ul>
    
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
          </li>
    
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/usuario/register">Cadastro</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    
      <div class="starter-template">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            
    <div class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" href="/">
        <a href="/">
          <div class="media">
            
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="180px" height="360px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64">
              <title>Placeholder</title>
              <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect>
              <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">...</text>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>
    
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </main>
```

I am pretty sure the problem is with my `z-index` settings, because the issue start when I add that. I need this to keep the navbar behind the `list-group`, but without make the links in the navbar unavailable.

Comment: the `container-fluid` element is above the `navbar` , so you can click the navbar. I think you are using bootstrap? check bootstrap documentation for the navbar, your design wont work like this. you'll need to reduce container width or put the navbar on top or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In is because have kept z-index=-1, because if that it is getting stacked lower compared to other element. Either remove it or make it greater than or equal to zero.